# Scrolling Performance Chrome vs Firefox (while using ngx-virtual-scroller)

Tags: angular, performance, google-chrome, firefox, smooth-scrolling

The scrolling in **Chrome** is **not** smooth.
Whereas in **Firefox** its a lot smoother.
The list is dynamically generated using `ngx-virtual-scroller`.
My guess is that firefox **debounces** the scroll event and create smooth effect although the content loaded a bit late but its smoother and I want that effect on chrome as well.

[Here is the website link (**Pokedex**)](https://hybridshivam.tech/pokedex)

Another observation is that on **Chrome Android** (touch) the scrolling is smooth like firefox.
I have also verified this using **chrome dev tools** and simulating as a ***mobile device(touch)*** and it results in the desired smooth effect but on ***desktop mode*** it starts to lag while scrolling.

I just want to improve the scrolling performance of the list.
Without ngx-virtual-scroller it was smooth but the whole list was in the DOM so realtime searching was a bit slow so I switched to it but it resulted in lagged scrolling in chrome and that's my favourite browser.

Comment: its smooth for me in chrome. Can you update your chrome?

Comment: Hey reallly????? 
I think my chrome is updated as well

Comment: yes, i opened link you gave above. and its works fine.

Comment: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Its updated can you please confirm that the scrolling on my webapp is smooth?

Comment: lol, mine is Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: What happens if you scroll too fast???

Comment: its working fine for me, for your pokedex application.

Comment: I am having this issue since the beginning and it frustrates me a lot now : (

Comment: ahhh got it, if at first load you directly go to bottom, it loads all page one by one. which angular version you are using?

Comment: use this :- https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling

Comment: Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 13.12.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.2

Comment: but virtual scrolling does not support multi column that's why i was using ngx-virtual-scroller
And during the initial load i have programmed it to load Pokemons 50 at a time so after the initial loading (all 807 loaded) I'm talking about this instance if the list scrolling is instantaneous or lagged.

Comment: multi column? you can use flex layout which displayed as multicolumn but truly not is multicolumn. And ur current implementation only lags when i suddenly move from top to last when its still loading images.

Comment: or wrap your one single row in a component. that way it will no more be multicolumn.

Comment: This is how i implemented it as cdk-virtual-scroll
but I dont know how to use the flex layout as you said I'have tried it but no idea on how to get it working.

`<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="height: 90vh" itemSize="128" minBufferPx="150" maxBufferPx="250">
  <span *cdkVirtualFor="let pokemon of pokemons |  searchFilter: searchItem ; let i = index; templateCacheSize: 0">
    <app-pokemon-item [pokemon]="pokemon"></app-pokemon-item>
  </span>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>`

Comment: Not sure then. i believe your current implementation should be acceptable. you go in any virtual scroll implementation it will take some time for images to load if you suddenly move  scroll like that. in normal cases you implementation runs fine. or you can implement your custom debounce login maybe.

Comment: Ok I'll try it on other systems as well but currently I got no other devices  to check it but just wanted it to behave as it does in firefox and chrome android
you can also see that using the chrome device toolbar and select a android device or ipad and you'll see what I'm talking about(it behaves like firefox scroll and is smooth)

Comment: If you use a horizontal scroller to see a column in the middle AND after that you use the vertical scroller. The Chromium engine fails to update the data buffer and the table is jumping around in the current loaded viewPort, whenever you use the vertical scroller.

Same with Edge browser. Firefox works fine. So this seems to be a problem with the chromium engine.

Has anybody faced the same problem or has a solution for it?